# How to use Docker for Windows only in command line, with GUI bypassed/disabled?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, containers

I work with Windows containers on Windows 10 Pro.

Is it enough just to run *dockerd* process in PowerShell to use Docker? Should I need some other processes/services running?

I still don't understand the purpose of *com.docker.service* (*Docker Desktop Service*). I pull images and run containers without it.

Am I missing something?

**Edit:** It is not possible to switch container mode with *DockerCli.exe* **without** *com.docker.service* running, but when it does, it creates *MobyLinuxVM* to run Linux containers. It may be the main purpose of having the service enabled.

**Question:** Do I need the *Docker Desktop Service* when I only work in Windows containers mode?

**Question:** Why running Windows container in *hyperv* isolation mode does not create Hyper-V VM? I've double checked it Hyper-V Manager.

Answer (score 1):

When you run linux containers on windows, tyou don't run in on windows but on hyperv machine with linux installed.

Windows containers are ran by windows native dockerd.

This additional gui helps you manage which type of container you're using at the moment. Probably you could live without it, but is it worth it? It might in the newer version (didn't test that) provide the connectivity betwen linux and windows containers, so I'd be careful with disabling that service.

Just to note, this is only for desktop windows. For windows server you can and should use docker ee (basic version is only for windows and it's free)

Comment: To be precise, I am testing it on Windows 10 Pro. For Windows containers the default isolation mode is _hyperv_, but it may be switched to _process_. Even if it's set to _hyperv_, no VM is created by Hyper-V on _docker run_ command (btw. no GUI invloved, just _dockerd_ process is running). Anyway I found out than I cannot switch from Windows containers to Linux when _com.docker.service_ is not running. If it is, it tries to crate MobyLinuxVM to run Linux container. That could be the main purpose of the service.

Comment: That was my point. For server setups you don't have this service as docker ee provides only native Windows containers, no Moby Linux and switching. Just docker and dockerd.

Comment: I understand. In the meantime I also found why Hyper-V Manager does not list Windows VM when isolation mode is _hyperv_: _(...) while Hyper-V is the runtime technology powering hyper-v isolation, hyper-v isolated containers are not Hyper-V VMs and cannot be managed with classic Hyper-V tools_, it' mentioned here: https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/dockerforws2016/